# Not able to take screenshot in Android L programmatically

Tags: java, android, screenshot

I'm using Nexus 5. Version 5.1.1

I want to take screenshot programmatically of phone at any given time. I'm okay if the solution is specific to Nexus 5.

After reading many answers, I've tried below solution using `screencap`.

Issue is it creates image file, but it is blank.

```
private void takeSS() {
    try {

        if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {

            Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/screencap -p /storage/emulated/0/img.png\n");
            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

            outputStream.flush();
            su.waitFor();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(su.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String output = line + System.getProperty("line.separator");
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The same command if I run from command prompt, it executes successfully.
Please suggest what might be the issue.

P.S. - My phone is rooted.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried executing the command as su?

`"/system/bin/su -c \"/system/bin/screencap -p /storage/emulated/0/img.png\""`

Comment: It gives error `java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/system/bin/su, -c, "/system/bin/screencap, -p, /storage/emulated/0/img.png"] Working Directory: null Environment: null`